# Cast std::vector as another std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

I need to convert vector of triangles to thrice longer vector of indices:

```
struct Triangle { int16_t v[3] };

std::vector<Triangle>
std::vector<int16_t>
```

Maybe I can somehow convert iterators of an already-initialized vector from the raw memory it encapsulates?

EDIT: that is true, i don't want any copies.

Comment: What is i16? Please post real code.

Comment: You can't do that with a simple cast, sorry.

Comment: @NeilKirk I think the intent of the question is clear even if you don't have a definition of `i16`.

Comment: Do you mean to make a _new_ vector, or treat the former as the latter in some cases? If the latter option, with casting you can [get close](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16641131/560648) but alignment quickly becomes an issue; you should create an iterator that delves into each element of the vector and pretends that each is actually three elements.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: An iterator range can do just fine. You can even use it to copy everything into a new vector, thus satisfying even the most literal interpretation of the problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom But then see answers making assumptions about the type.

Comment: @Neil: The specific type is not all that relevant here, honestly.

Comment: @lightness in theory, iterator should check if they are packed and ordered right and alignment is good: if so, should reinterpret the block of memory.  If that fails, put in checks that make it fail to compile, and leave comments on how to fix for your new platform... ;)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that.

However you can do this:

```
std::vector<Triangle> ts;
__int16 *pvbegin = ts[0].v;
__int16 *pvend = pvbegin + 3 * ts.size();
```

And use the pair `pvbegin` and `pvend` as an iterator range.

I'm not positively sure that it is not a technical Undefined Behavior, but it should work fine. To be sure it is a good idea to add a `static_assert` somewhere such as:

```
static_assert(sizeof(Triangle) == 3*sizeof(int16_t), "Weird sizeof(Triangle)");
```

Comment: You're assuming `sizeof(Triangle) == sizeof(__int16)*3`, but I'd be astounded if this were the case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Why? I would be surprised if this were not the case. No extra alignment requirements, not extra padding requirements. Maybe the compiler is allowed to add padding at the end of the struct, but there is not a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Actually, fair enough, surprisingly I'm not seeing padding here. It's still a mortally dangerous assumption to make.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not so. In every ABI I know of, a struct with a single element has the same size and alignment as that element. And arrays never have padding. So my original assumption holds.

Comment: At the very least, your assumption needs an `assert`ion to go with it.

Comment: I think that it CAN work on 32bit x86 machine, but may fail on 64bit machine and for sure will on ARM architecture

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Fair enough. I've added a `static_assert()`.

Comment: @firda: I've checked in x86, x86_64 and ARM (Raspberry Pi) and everywhere `sizeof(Triangle)==6`. The only reason why that would be different would be if the alignment requirement of the structure would be greater than `sizeof(int16_t)`. But the normal struct aligment is that of their most strictly aligned member. And the alignment of an array is that of the member of the array.

Comment: @rodrigo: hmm, maybe you are correct .... but that would mean, that casting vector<Triangle> to const vector<uint_16> could actually be safe! (if we assume that there is no specialization)

Comment: and it trully works on my PC (old 32bit notebook with XP, compiled by cygwin gcc): std::vector<int16_t>& cast = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int16_t>*>(&vect);

Comment: @firda: No, that would depend on the implementation of `std::vector` and that is way beyond the platform ABI specification. Casting a `Triangle(&)[N]` to a `int16_t(&)[3*N]` may be fine. But casting `vector<A>&` to `vector<B>&` is totally different. If `vector` is implemented as a pair of pointers it might work. But if it is a pointer and a count it will not. Since you should not assume any implementation of `vector` you should definitely **not** do that.

Comment: @firda: Also, remember that the standard library implementators are smart people that will do very smart things to make your `vector` work faster and better. Any of these smart ideas can go very wrong if you start breaking the rules.

Comment: Ok, +1 from me then. Though please add that rationale into your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a smart way, or just a way that works?

```
std::vector<int16_t> vec_int;
std::vector<Triangle> vec_tri;
for (const auto& tri : vec_tri)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vec_int.push_back(tri.v[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because although I suspect the OP doesn't want any copies, he hasn't said so, so this answer satisfies the literal interpretation of the question.

Comment: `vec_int.reserve(vec_tri.size() * 3);`?

Answer (score 2):

**BIG EDIT:** This seems to be correct and easy (all tested)

```
static_assert(sizeof(Triangle) == 3*sizeof(int16_t),
    "Weird sizeof(Triangle)");
struct SimpleWrapper {
private:
    std::vector<Triangle>& vect;
public:
    SimpleWrapper(std::vector<Triangle>& vect)
    : vect(vect) {
    }
    int16_t* begin() {
        return vect[0].v;
    }
    int16_t* end() {
        return begin() + vect.size()*3;
    }
};
```

**ORIGINAL:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Triangle { int16_t v[3]; };

struct Iterator: std::iterator<
  std::input_iterator_tag,
  int16_t> {
private:
    std::vector<Triangle>& vect;
    int index, subidx;
public:
    Iterator(
      std::vector<Triangle>& vect,
      int index, int subidx)
    : vect(vect), index(index), subidx(subidx) {
    }
    Iterator(const Iterator& src)
    : vect(src.vect), index(src.index), subidx(src.subidx) {
    }
    Iterator& operator++() {
        if(++subidx == 3) {
            subidx = 0; index++;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Iterator operator++(int) {
        Iterator tmp(*this);
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }
    bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) {
        return &rhs.vect == &vect
          && rhs.index == index
          && rhs.subidx == subidx;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    int16_t& operator*() {
        return vect[index].v[subidx];
    }
};

struct Wrapper {
private:
    std::vector<Triangle>& vect;
public:
    Wrapper(std::vector<Triangle>& vect)
    : vect(vect) {
    }
    Iterator begin() {
        return Iterator(vect, 0, 0);
    }
    Iterator end() {
        return Iterator(vect, vect.size(), 0);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Triangle> vect;
    vect.push_back(Triangle { 1,2,3 });
    vect.push_back(Triangle { 6,7,8 });

    Wrapper wrap(vect);
    for (int16_t v : wrap)
        std::cout << v << ' ';
}
```

Comment: this still does not do the desired cast (which is impossible).

Comment: he asked for iterator, he got it (direct cast won't be safe because sizeof(Triangle) == 2*4 instaead of 2*3 due to padding)

Comment: Why the == operator not const method?

Comment: well, it actually does not matter. const can be added to all functions not changing the state, but const_iterator is something different than const iterator

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not, since accessing the vector's 'length' will almost certainly be wrong. There may be other opaque implementation details that will be wrong too. At best you might be able to cast:

```
#include <type_traits>
...
static_assert(sizeof(Triangle) == (sizeof(int16_t) * 3) &&
              std::is_standard_layout<Triangle>::value),
              "Triangle does not satisfy contiguous storage requirements");

// i-th triangle from: std::vector<int16_t> values
Triangle *t = reinterpret_cast<Triangle *>(& values[i * 3]);
```

The standard doesn't make many guarantees about `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I need to pass whole vector to a function of a library which doesn't know about Triangle type.

Comment: @Yola: Then I'd do this the other way around; store `std::vector<int16_t>`, but make an iterator facade so you can treat it like a range of `Triangle` when you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you only really care about how you *access* the data, rather than literally whether it is stored in a `std::vector<int16_t>`, you could make your own iterator to iterate over the vertices in sequence. If the iterator is currently at the first vertex of a triangle, incrementing it would bring you to the second vertex; from the second vertex, incrementing would bring you to the third vertex; and from the third vertex, incrementing would give you the first vertex of the next triangle.

You could also make an object that provided "random access" to the vertices of the triangles, taking as input a number from 0 to number_of_triangles-1, inclusive.